# Прозрачный с одной, непрозрачный, с другой Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Как сделать, чтобы с одной стороны допустим куб был прозрачен, а с противоположной стороны был непрозрачный? Как это реализовать?

Comment: a) Построить свою геометрию, взяв за основу геометрию куба, без одной стороны. б) Передать в конструктор меша с геометрией куба, в параметр для материала массив из 6 материалов, один из которых либо null, либо имеет в настройках `transparent: true, opacity: 0`

Comment: Ну, и хорошо бы показать референсную картинку, чтоб было понятно - что именно нужно.